# Query timeout on MS SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have a Java webapp accessing MSSQL database on a MS SQL Server 2012 running on the same machine.

Some of the queries fail after exactly 3 seconds with:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The query has timed out.
```

It happens a couple of times a day, in the mornings, when the app is not heavy loaded.
On average the queries took less than 50 ms.

I'm using Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 and the queries will fail after exactly 3 seconds even if I use `statement.setQueryTimeout(0);`
Remote query timeout on the server is set to its default value (600s).

Any idea why the queries fail after 3s?

**Edit**:

Here are some of the queries:

```
UPDATE CampaignCalls SET note = 'Short Text' WHERE (saveTime IS NULL) AND (agent = ?)
```

This one updates no more than 50 rows

```
INSERT INTO CampaignCustomers (campaignId, clientId, completed, callTime)
SELECT ?, clientId, 0, callTime 
FROM CampaignCustomers WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE campaignId = ?
```

This one copies no more than 1500 rows.

The connection to the server doesn't break. I'm reusing it a moment later with no problems.

I am wondering why the 3 seconds? Is there any other timeout setting I am not seeing? Even if the table is locked for some reason, why is the query timing out after **exactly** 3s?

Thank you all!

Comment: Post one of those queries

Comment: the failure is always at the same time of the day? did you check if there is any ongoing backup job or similar task?

Comment: the failure is `about` the same time of the day (+/- a 30 min) and there are no other running tasks.

Comment: what happens if you add 'AND 1 = 2' to the where statement ? It should insert 0 rows, but if that fails it indicate that the issue is somewhere else

Comment: It will probably fail, yes. The question is... what can I do to track it down? Why exactly 3s?

Comment: this is not an sql question and there is no way for anyone to tell why your connection is gone

Comment: The connection is not gone. I'm reusing it a moment later, executing queries without timing out. I was wondering if anyone know anything about a 3s timeout. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ivan any chance you got this resolved?

Comment: @SundaraBalajiJK, can't remember exactly, but it was something really really dumb. Turned out that some application logic was setting a 3s timeout... but can't remember any details now (it was 4 years ago).